# How to get post with slug and exclude categories

Tags: posts, categories, get-posts, exclude

I want to do a query to get posts with a slug and `category__not_in`. Here's what I do:

```
$query = array(
    "name" => "test",
    "category__not_in" => array( 15 )
);
query_posts( $query );
```

When printing the result on the screen, I get the given post - but it contains a category which I excluded. I want when I submit `category__not_in` it doesn't return any results, but it returns the post.

Post with slug `test` contains category 15, but I specifically say if the `slug` is test and there is no category 15, then show it to me. How can I tell WordPress to execute this condition?

Comment: Forgive me, but It's not clear to me what you're asking for. You wrote, *"I want when I submit category__not_in it doesn't return any results, but it returns the post."*. Huh? Can you explain further please?

Answer (score 1):

Please read [this Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) why you should not use `query_posts()`.

If you really want to use `query_posts()`:

```
query_posts(
    'name' => 'test',
    'category' => '-15' // notice "minus 15"
);
```

The right way to exclude category:

```
$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'name' => 'test',
        'category__not_in' => array(15)
    )
);

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    .....
}
```

Comment: These scripts don't work. If i put only category, it works. If i add name it doesn't work. Any idea ?